# PyTorch SimCSE loss implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp

I’m looking to implement the supervised [Simple Contrastive Learning of Sentence Embeddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.08821) (SimCSE) loss using positive and negative pairs with PyTorch.

[image: -\log_e \left( \frac{{\text{sim}(h_i,h_i^+)}}{\tau} \frac{1}{{\sum_{j=1}^{N} e^{\frac{{\text{sim}(h_i,h_i^+)}}{\tau}} + e^{\frac{{\text{sim}(h_i,h_i^-)}}{\tau}}} \right)]

Is there a way to vectorize the naïve implementation below with broadcasting operations and/or matrix multiplication?

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


batch_size = 4
feature_dim = 1024
h = -2*torch.randn(batch_size, 3, feature_dim)+1  # (batch dim, contrastive triplet, features dim)
temp = 10

num = torch.exp(F.cosine_similarity(h[:, 0, :], h[:, 1, :], dim=1) / temp)

denom = torch.empty_like(num)
for j in range(batch_size):
    denomjj = 0
    for jj in range(batch_size):
        denomjj += torch.exp(F.cosine_similarity(h[j, 0, :], h[jj, 1, :], dim=0) / temp)
        denomjj += torch.exp(F.cosine_similarity(h[j, 0, :], h[jj, 2, :], dim=0) / temp)
    denom[j] = denomjj

loss = -torch.log(num / denom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Your numerator seems fine so I'll vectorize the denominator.

I'll try to stick to your notation as closely as I can:

```
norm_hi = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.square(h[:, 0, :]), dim=1))
norm_hj_plus = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.square(h[:, 1, :]), dim=1))
norm_hj_minus = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(torch.square(h[:, 2, :]), dim=1))

sim_denom1 = torch.outer(norm_hi, norm_hj_plus) * temp
sim_denom2 = torch.outer(norm_hi, norm_hj_minus) * temp

v1 = h[:, 0, :] @ h[:, 1, :].t() / sim_denom1
v2 = h[:, 0, :] @ h[:, 2, :].t() / sim_denom2

vec_denom = torch.sum(torch.exp(v1) + torch.exp(v2), dim=1)
```

You can verify that this computes your denominator like this:

```
print(torch.allclose(loss, -torch.log(num / vec_denom)))
```